# jquery autocomplete returning all labels

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following code calling the jquery autocomplete widget:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#vendor_name" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'vendor_names.php',
        minLength: 3
})
});
```

My `vendor_names.php` file looks something like:

```
<?php
include("include/db_connect.php");

$query = "select VendorName from Vendor where VendorCancelDate is NULL order by 
VendorName";
$result = mssql_query($query);
while ( $record = mssql_fetch_array($result) ){
        $vendors[] = array('label' => $record['VendorName']);
}
echo json_encode($vendors);

?>
```

But when I type anything, it always returns everything in my query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the value of the input to the script:

```
$(function() {
        var val = $( "#vendor_name" ).val();
        $( "#vendor_name" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'vendor_names.php?token=' + val,
        minLength: 3
   });
});
```

Filter the results returned by the script.  You will want to do this in a manner that doesn't concatenate the sql to avoid sql injection, but just for an example:

```
<?php
include("include/db_connect.php");
$val = $_GET["token"];
$query = "select VendorName from Vendor where VendorCancelDate is NULL and VendorName like '%". $val . "%' order by VendorName";
$result = mssql_query($query);
while ( $record = mssql_fetch_array($result) ){
        $vendors[] = array('label' => $record['VendorName']);
}
echo json_encode($vendors);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge you need to pass **the input** by the user to `vendor_names.php?input=whatever`..
and your query must be
`select VendorName from Vendor where VendorCancelDate is NULL and VendorName=%whatever%' order by VendorName`